# How to temporarily change default version of gcc in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, gcc

I have ArchLinux and 2 versions of gcc installed on it. default one ("gcc") which is "gcc (GCC) 7.1.1" and "gcc-5" one which is "gcc-5 (GCC) 5.4.0".

I have a hard time building some projects that check the version of gcc (and g++) to be less than or equal to 5. (to be more specific installing official run-file of cuda-8.0 from nvidia, or building projects which have used cuda library and its header files)

all I want is to change default version of gcc on my environment (temporarily) and set it back later when i'm done, something like "update-alternatives" solution in debian-like distros.

here is some information about binaries related to gcc and g++ at my /usr/bin :

```
$ ls -l | grep gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        3 Jun 30 16:49 cc -> gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root   997840 Jun 30 16:49 gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root   873352 Jul 11  2016 gcc-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    27104 Jun 30 16:49 gcc-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    25544 Jul 11  2016 gcc-ar-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root   875720 Jul 11  2016 gccgo-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    27104 Jun 30 16:49 gcc-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    25512 Jul 11  2016 gcc-nm-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    27104 Jun 30 16:49 gcc-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    25512 Jul 11  2016 gcc-ranlib-5
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root   997840 Jun 30 16:49 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root   873352 Jul 11  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-5
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root   873352 Jul 11  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-5.4.0
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root   997840 Jun 30 16:49 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-7.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    27104 Jun 30 16:49 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    25544 Jul 11  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root   875720 Jul 11  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gccgo-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    27104 Jun 30 16:49 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    25512 Jul 11  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    27104 Jun 30 16:49 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    25512 Jul 11  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-5
```

Comment: What happens if you set the environment variable `CC=gcc-5` when building the project? (And likewise for `CXX=whateverg++5iscalledhere`)

Comment: sometimes this solution doesn't work, especially on projects like opencv or... with dedicated cmake scripts to detect gcc version. (or I'm using it wrong)

Comment: Almost all autoconf-based build systems will honor `PATH`. Create a directory `$HOME/oldstuff`, symlink `gcc` in that directory to `/usr/bin/gcc-5`. Add that directory to the front of `PATH` before building software that requires the old gcc.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick :  looks like a neat solution, thank you.
for future readers: you can override compiler version checking using --override : "cuda-<version>.run --override" (i just found it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR**: `sudo ln -s $(which gcc-5) /usr/local/bin/gcc; hash -r`

By default, the gcc binary is located in `/usr/bin`

Checking our path, we see that `/usr/local/bin` comes first:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
. . .
```

So, assuming we installed gcc-5 (`yaourt --noconfirm -S gcc5`) we can make that the "default" version by creating a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` like so:

```
sudo ln -s $(which gcc-5) /usr/local/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s $(which g++-5) /usr/local/bin/g++
```

Next, we need to rehash gcc to remove the old, remembered gcc location:

```
hash -r
```

To restore the original "default" version of gcc we just need to delete that symlink and rehash:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/g++
hash -r
```

Comment: Is it ok to set icc and icpc this way? will cmake and other app will use this directly by just doing this?

Comment: I also needed to set these shell variables:

```bash
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
```